# clCreateContext takes a lot of time in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia

I am working on an openCL program, and everything is working good, but the problem is that clCreateContext function call takes most of the program execution time (the program runs in about 400 ms where 380 ms just for creating context).

The kernel is compiled online after creating context and command queue. And my system contains just one OpenCL device (Nvidia Pascal).

I tried the same program on Nvidia GeForce GT 640, and it takes less time for creating context (about 100 ms), but still too large comparing to the execution time (I printed the device names and they are all good).

```
vector<cl_platform_id> platforms;
cl_device_id device_id;
clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &ret_num_platforms);
ret = clGetPlatformIDs(ret_num_platforms, &platforms[0], NULL);
ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], deviceType, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
timeStamps[0] = get_timestamp();
context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
timeStamps[1] = get_timestamp();
contextTime=(timeStamps[1]-timeStamps[0]) / 1000.0L;
cout << "   Context Time: " << contextTime << " ms\n";
command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &ret);
```

Comment: Why do you think it is too slow? It seems like this is the type of call you would use once during an execution.

Comment: I have created previous openCL programs, and clCreateContext didn't take that much time, build program maybe, but I thought creating context is not a process that takes that much time (Program builld time is 7 ms and creating context is 380 ms !), does that make sense?

Comment: Did you consider passing a `char*` to see if you have any error messages?

Comment: Yes, that's just a simplified version, I have an error check function under each call, and the program works perfectly without any problem.

Comment: In a typical OpenCL application you would create context only once and expect program to spend most of its time in actual computation done on OpenCL device. So it shouldn't matter much if clCreateContext takes lot of time. But in some cases if this becomes bottleneck then driver vendor has to fix this. Anything could be happening, some kernels might be built etc.